# Как подключить базу данных к Spring security?

Tags: java, sql, spring

Пытаюсь в программу со Spring Security, где авторизация проходила без использования базы данных(просто с одним вписанным в программу пользователем) добавить вышеупомянутую, но скудное понимание Spring Security мешает мне это сделать.

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Context initialization failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh
(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;
Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized 
call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root 
WebApplicationContext
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что я не так делаю?

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
@Autowired
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and();

    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll();

    http.logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService(){
return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
}

}
```

Role, User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String role;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

protected Role(){}
public Role(String name)
{
    role = name;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
Set<User> users;

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return getRole();
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "username")
private String login;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

public User(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

public User() {

}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

UserDetails:

```
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
User findByLogin(String username);
}

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UsersRepository userRep;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails loadedUser;

    try {
        User client = userRep.findByLogin(email);
        loadedUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                client.getLogin(), client.getPassword(),
                client.getRoles());
    } catch (Exception repositoryProblem) {
        throw new 
InternalAuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), 
repositoryProblem);
    }
    return loadedUser;
}
```

pom.xml

```
   <properties>
    <spring.mvc>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <spring.securiry>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.securiry>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `@ComponentScan("com")` и приведите скрипт сборки с указанием зависимостей и их версий

Comment: Без ComponentScan все тоже самое, добавил зависимости

Comment: Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677464/3212712) у вас проблема в конфликте разных версий модулей спринга. Т.е. надо их одинаковыми сделать. Попробуйте поднять `hibernate` и `data`

Comment: Спасибо, поднял Spring до 5.0 и пошли уже более конкретные ошибки. А в самом коде все более-менее правильно?

Comment: Да, в коде всё, кажется, как нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677464/3212712) у вас не находится метод:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh
```

Этот метод добавлен в 4 версии спринга. А у вас есть зависимости для 3 версии (`Hibernate`) которые и пытаются этот метод вызвать после чего и падают.

Выход - привести версии зависимостей к единой мажорной версии, например `4` или `5`